# Changing Different background image based on screen :- css HTML5 Gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

Concept is simple, I have a html5 page and it is responsive , just the bground images does not change with the screen size : right now code is:

```
<div id="home-gallery" class="gallery-container fullscreen">
<section id="home-welcome" class="slide-1 gallery-slide background-cover" style="background-image:url(static/img/home/image1.jpg)">
.....

<section id="home-campaigns" class="slide-2 gallery-slide background-cover" style="background-image:url(static/img/home/image2.jpg)">
```

That said it using one common image. What I tried doing in CSS is:

```
@media (min-width:800px) { background-image: url(bg-800.jpg) }
@media (min-width:1024px) { background-image: url(bg-1024.jpg) }
@media (min-width:1280px) { background-image: url(bg-1280.jpg) }
```

But I am not sure how to associate `style="background-image:` property to css code? should I write:

```
<section id="home-campaigns" class="slide-2 gallery-slide background-cover" style="background-image">
```

and in css `#home-welcome background-image
@media (min-width:800px) { background-image: url(bg-1024.jpg) }
@media (min-width:1024px) { background-image: url(bg-1024.jpg) }
@media (min-width:1280px) { background-image: url(bg-1280.jpg) }`

Please help. I tried. `

Comment: Do you have "one common image" or three images?

Answer (score 2):

```
@media (min-width:800px) { 
#home-welcome{
background-image: url(bg-800.jpg);
}
}
@media (min-width:1024px) {
#home-welcome{
 background-image: url(bg-1024.jpg);
}
}
@media (min-width:1280px) {
#home-welcome{
 background-image: url(bg-1280.jpg);
}
}
```

This would set the background image of home-welcome div according to screen size.

Although using the min-width, all three rules would match. You should use max-width instead.

Edit : I take my statement about max-width back. Depends onw hat you want to achieve. Just keep in my mind that css rules cascade when multiple rules match and the last declared rule wins. Use !important wisely.

Corresponding html

```
<section id="home-welcome" class="slide-2 gallery-slide background-cover">
```

Also check this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

You can use `background-size:contain` so that the image fits the container div.

Comment: @cowboybepop, I tried but looks like not working. How should I include in my html code? <section id="home-campaigns" class="slide-2 gallery-slide background-cover" style="background-image"> ?

Comment: If you id is home-campaigns then the corresponding id should be used in the css rule. You don't have to add an online style again. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: @cowboybepop It is actly gallery with different Id', first one is home -welcome as I have mentioned in my first comment

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. I added an edit with a url which may be useful.